# XSLT1: Using xsl:element how to include current selection of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

I try to create nodes using xsl:element in a way to include all the attributes of the current selection. I thought it should be simple, but for some reason, I could not get the result.

I isolated the case, there is the XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="myfile.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<a firstAtt="1" secondAtt="2">
    Some Text
</a>
```

I am expecting getting this result:

```
<a firstAtt="1" secondAtt="2"/>
```

There is my XSLT transformation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}" use-attribute-sets="{@*}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Without go in depth, I made tons of attempts of that kind of approach. (including `xsl:for-each`, `xsl:attribute` etc.)

I could understand that `use-attribute-sets` couldn't work that way (meaning targeting to the current set of attributes at run time). Maybe I'm wrong.

This is for an assessment and there is a restriction to not use xsl:copy. There is also a restriction to make it work in XSLT 1.0

I'm newbie in XML - XSL. Thank in advance if someone could help and for your understanding.

Comment: If you cannot use `xsl:copy`, then use `xsl:attribute` to recreate an attribute - same as you do with elements. To recreate all atributes, use either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` with another template matching attributes.

Comment: Who on earth sets assignments to write code with not one, but both, hands tied behind your back? (Or is `xsl:copy-of` allowed, perhaps? For attributes, copy and copy-of do the same thing.)

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your help. We figured out. It it possible to do it without xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of. (See Pierre's answer) I think the teacher wants to push us on the "training bench". Now I got out of my stuck position. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly what you mean by the "current selection", but this XSL stylesheet could do what you expect, at least for the input you provide:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Bonjour Pierre, yes that is exactly what I was trying to do. Considering other comments above then I was figure out again and I came to the same result as yours. Thanks!!!